# Compute the possibilities for $\gcd (2a^4 + 2a^2+3,2a^5+2a^3+a^2+a+3)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, gcd-and-lcm

> Given that $a$ is an integer, compute the possibilities for $\gcd (2a^4 + 2a^2+3,2a^5+2a^3+a^2+a+3).$

Here's my work (I'm not entirely sure if it's correct).

Just to make sure we're on the same page, we say that for integers $a,b,$ $d=\gcd(a,b)$ is the integer such that $d\mid a$ and $d\mid b$ and for all $c\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $c\mid a$ and $c\mid b,c\mid d$ (so there can be multiple possible $gcd$'s).

We use the fact that $\gcd (a,b)=\gcd(b,a-bq),q\in\mathbb{Z}.$

Dividing using the Euclidean Algorithm, we have the following:

$2a^5+2a^3+a^2+a+3=(2a^4+2a^2+3)(a)+a^2-2a+3\\
2a^4+2a^2+3=(a^2-2a+3)(2a^2+4a+4)-4a-9\\
4(a^2-2a+3)=4a^2-8a+12=(-4a-9)(-a+4)-a+48\\
-4a-9=4(-a+48)-201.$

Hence $\gcd (2a^5+2a^3+a^2+a+3,2a^4+2a^2+3)=\gcd (-a+48,-201)$ for all $a\in\mathbb{Z}.$ Let $f(a)=48-a, f:\mathbb{Z}\to \mathbb{Z}.$ Then since $f$ is a surjective, monic linear polynomial, the possibilities for $\gcd (-a+48,-201)$ are precisely the integer divisors of $201$ (since $\gcd$'s can be negative according to the definition).

> Edit: I've edited my answer to include the proper possibilities.

Comment: $\gcd$ can't be negative

Comment: I think you mean $\gcd(a,b) = \gcd(b,a-bq)$.

Comment: @aschepler aw yes I do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trusting on your calculations, it is enough to find the possible values of $\gcd(48-a, -201)$. Now, assume $f(a):=48-a, f:\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}$. Since, $f$ is monic linear polynomial it is surjective. Therefore, possibilities of  $\gcd(48-a, -201)$ will be all positive divisors of $201$.

Comment: I don't think that gcd can be negative! Suppose you are true, then $\gcd(a,b)=-d$, $d>0$. But note that $d|a, d|b~\& ~d$ is bigger than $-d$ so contradiction.

Comment: No, according to the definition I provided, the gcd can be negative. I know however that by convention the gcd is positive. The gcd according to the given definition is maximal according to the operation $\mid$ (divide).